# Append CSV files and assign column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Python to loop through a list of CSV's (file locations are in df) and append them to one dataframe. The script is close to being done, but I run into trouble when attempting to add a column to each dataframe that includes a name reference from df.

I've tried multiple variations of the below script, with the current one correctly looping through each CSV but returning only 1 class reference instead of all. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('MLBPitchesvsLHH.csv') #File contains 4 columns of data - Column1=Pitch; Column2=FileName; Column3=FileLoc; Column4=Class
df.to_dict('series')

combo_df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in df.loc[ : ,"FileLoc"]: #This loop opens each file located in df
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file)  
    for pitch in df.loc[ : ,"Class"]: #This loop is supposed to add a column to df1 that includes the "Class" reference from df
        df1 = df1.assign(pitch=pitch)

    combo_df = combo_df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)

combo_df.to_csv("Pitches.csv")
```

Comment: So each df1 should have multiple columns equal to pitch in df ? For example you have 4 row in df , df1 should have four pitch ?

Comment: The for pitch loop is assigning the last item in the series to the column pitch.  A query df.loc[df['FileLoc'] == file, 'Class'] may return the Class form the matching line and set it to the whole column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your description , by using `assign` with `dict` will achieve what you need.

```
combo_df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in df.loc[ : ,"FileLoc"]: #This loop opens each file located in df
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file)
    df1=df1.assign(**dict(zip(df1["Class"].astype(str), df1["Class"].astype(str))))
    combo_df = combo_df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
```

Or

```
combo_df = pd.DataFrame()

for file,pitch in zip(df.loc[ : ,"FileLoc"],df.loc[ : ,"Class"]): #This loop opens each file located in df
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file)
    df1=df1.assign(pitch=pitch)
    combo_df = combo_df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)

combo_df.to_csv("Pitches.csv")
```

Comment: @Nick yw:-) happy coding